# Group numeric vector by predefined maximal group sum

Tags: r, vector, grouping, cumulative-sum, cumsum

I have a numeric vector like this `x <- c(1, 23,  7,  10,  9,  2,  4)` and I want to group the elements from left to right with the constrain that each group sum must not exceed `25`. Thus, here the first group is `c(1, 23)`, the second is `c(7, 10)` and the last `c(9, 2, 4)`. the expected output is a dataframe with a second column containing the groups:

```
data.frame(x= c(1, 23,  7,  10,  9,  2,  4), group= c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3))
```

I have tried different things with `cumsum` but am not able to kind of dynamically restart cumsum for the new group once the limit sum of `25` for the last group is reached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using base R and cumsum (and lapply for iteration):

```
id <- c(seq(1, length(x),1)[!duplicated(cumsum(x) %/% 25)], length(x)+1)
id2 <- 1:length(id)
group <- unlist(lapply(1:(length(id)-1), function(x) rep(id2[x], diff(id)[x])))
data.frame(x=x, group=group)

   x group
1  1     1
2 23     1
3  7     2
4 10     2
5  9     3
6  2     3
7  4     3
```

**Edit: New Approach using recursive function**

Here is a new more efficient approach that should also cover the special case which @ЕгорШишунов considered and should work efficiently because it's written as a recursive function.

```
 recursiveFunction<- function(x, maxN=25, sumX=0, period=1, period2return=c()){
      sumX <- sumX + x[1]
      if (sumX >= maxN) { sumX=x[1]; period = period + 1}
      period2return <- c(period2return, period)
      if (length(x) == 1) { return(period2return)}
      return(recursiveFunction(x[-1], 25, sumX, period, period2return))
    }
    
    recursiveFunction(x, maxN=25)
```

Note that you should not change the entries for the last three function parameters (`sumX=0, period=1, period2return=c()`) because they are only important during the recursive call of the function.

Comment: Other questions are as good but that is the easiest to me to understand. Thanks

Comment: It is also wrong solution. For `x = c(10, 20, 20, 20)` it returns `c(1, 2, 3, 3)` but true answer is `c(1, 2, 3, 4)`. base function `cumsum` is bad for this task cause it forgets about the rests.

Comment: @ЕгорШишунов What do you mean with "it forgets about the rests"?

Comment: Let `x = c(10, 20, 20, 20)`,  `cumsum(x) = c(10, 30, 50, 70)`. And last 2 elements have group `3` (cause `50 %/% 25 == 70 %/% 25 == 2`). But if we solve problem by hand: sum of first and second elements is greater than 25 so they will be different groups (1 and 2). Sum of second and third element is greater than 25 so third element will be in group 3. And sum of last 2 elements is greater than 25 so the first element should be in group 4. We check sum of elements in last group (third element = 20) and new element (fourth element = 20) and `20 %/% 25 != 40 %/% 25` (we have not rest = 30).

Comment: @ЕгорШишунов I think not cumsum is the problem but the (combination with) `%/%` because I get the correct solution for `x = c(10, 20, 20, 20)` with the answer from "ThomasIsCoding" which is using `cumsum`, too.

Comment: You are right, I think the problem is that I'm using `cumsum` without any loop, or e.g. like Mael suggested with `accumulate` (which is by the way a very nice and pure solution).

Comment: Loop and vectorized function? It's bad case. If you can write loop in R you can do it in Rcpp. But Rcpp is faster.

Answer (score 6):

I think cpp function is the fastest way:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction(
    "IntegerVector GroupBySum(const NumericVector& x, const double& max_sum = 25)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        int cnt = 0;
        int period = 1;
        IntegerVector res(x.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i)
        {
            ++cnt;
            sum += x[i];
            if (sum > max_sum)
            {
                sum = x[i];
                if (cnt > 1)
                    ++period;
                cnt = 1;
            }
            res[i] = period;
        }
        return res;
    }"
)
GroupBySum(c(1, 23,  7,  10,  9,  2,  4), 25)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `cumsumbinning` built-in function from the MESS package:

```r
# install.packages("MESS")
MESS::cumsumbinning(x, 25, cutwhenpassed = F)
# [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 3
```

Or it can be done with `purrr::accumulate`:

```r
cumsum(x == accumulate(x, ~ifelse(.x + .y <= 25, .x + .y, .y)))
# [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 3
```

output

```r
group <- MESS::cumsumbinning(x, 25, cutwhenpassed = F)
data.frame(x= c(1, 23,  7,  10,  9,  2,  4), 
           group = group)

   x group
1  1     1
2 23     1
3  7     2
4 10     2
5  9     3
6  2     3
7  4     3
```

---

**Quick benchmark:**

```r
x<- c(1, 23,  7,  10,  9,  2,  4)
bm <- microbenchmark(
  fThomas(x),
  fThomasRec(x),
  fJKupzig(x), 
  fCumsumbinning(x), 
  fAccumulate(x),
  fReduce(x),
  fRcpp(x),
  times = 100L,
  setup = gc(FALSE)
)
autoplot(bm)
```

Егор Шишунов's `Rcpp` is the fastest, closely followed by `MESS::cumsumbinning` and ThomasIsCoding's both functions.

[image]

With `n = 100`, the gap gets bigger but `Rcpp` and `cumsumbinning` are still the top choices and the while loop option is no longer efficient (I had to remove ThomasIsCoding's functions because the execution time was too long):

```
x = runif(100, 1, 50)
```

[image]

Comment: your `accumulate` wont work eg `x<- c(1, 19, 24, 10, 9, 2, 4)`

Comment: Edited. It should work now.

Comment: Can you set `x = runif(100, 1, 50)`?. If size x = 1e5 Rcpp is much better (and loop in R is very bad) I want to know what is the test time if size = 100.

Comment: Done! Interesting results!

Comment: Could you add also the `recursiveFunction` to your results? I would be very interested to see the benchmark.

Comment: Added. For larger vector (`runif(100, 1, 50)`), I reach the stack size limit.

Answer (score 6):

We can try this as a programming practice if you like :)

```
f1 <- function(x) {
  group <- c()
  while (length(x)) {
    idx <- cumsum(x) <= 25
    x <- x[!idx]
    group <- c(group, rep(max(group, 0) + 1, sum(idx)))
  }
  group
}
```

or

```
f2 <- function(x) {
  group <- c()
  g <- 0
  while (length(x)) {
    cnt <- s <- 0
    for (i in seq_along(x)) {
      s <- s + x[i]
      if (s <= 25) {
        cnt <- cnt + 1
      } else {
        break
      }
    }
    g <- g + 1
    group <- c(group, rep(g, cnt))
    x <- x[-(1:cnt)]
  }
  group
}
```

or

```
f3 <- function(x) {
  s <- cumsum(x)
  r <- c()
  grp <- 1
  while (length(s)) {
    idx <- (s <= 25)
    r <- c(r, rep(grp, sum(idx)))
    grp <- grp + 1
    s <- s[!idx] - tail(s[idx], 1)
  }
  r
}
```

which gives

```
[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 3
```

and benchmarking among them looks like

```
set.seed(1)
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(1e3, 0, 25)
bm <- microbenchmark(
  f1(x),
  f2(x),
  f3(x),
  check = "equivalent"
)
autoplot(bm)
```

[image]

---

## Recursion version

Another option is using recursion (based on `f1()`)

```
f <- function(x, res = c()) {
  if (!length(x)) {
    return(res)
  }
  idx <- cumsum(x) <= 25
  Recall(x[!idx], res = c(res, list(x[idx])))
}
```

and you will see

```
> f(x)
[[1]]
[1]  1 23

[[2]]
[1]  7 10

[[3]]
[1] 9 2 4
```

Answer (score 5):

In base R you could also use `Reduce`:

```
do.call(rbind, Reduce(\(x,y) if((z<-x[1] + y) > 25) c(y, x[2]+1)
       else c(z, x[2]), x[-1], init = c(x[1], 1), accumulate = TRUE))

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]   24    1
[3,]    7    2
[4,]   17    2
[5,]    9    3
[6,]   11    3
[7,]   15    3
```

Breaking it down:

```
f <- function(x, y){
  z <- x[1] + y
  if(z > 25) c(y, x[2] + 1)
  else c(z, x[2])
}

do.call(rbind, Reduce(f, x[-1], init = c(x[1], 1), accumulate = TRUE))
```

if using `accumulate`

```
library(tidyverse)
accumulate(x[-1], f, .init = c(x[1], 1)) %>%
invoke(rbind, .)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]   24    1
[3,]    7    2
[4,]   17    2
[5,]    9    3
[6,]   11    3
[7,]   15    3
```